# How to integrate php code in a vuejs project for production building?

Tags: php, vue.js

Using CLI to generate a project with

```
vue create project
```

How can i integrate php code in .Vue files and not break the building command :

```
npm run build
```

As an example i want to add `<?php ?>` code inside the famous Home.vue view like so :

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="../assets/logo.png">
    <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/>
    <?php echo("this break the building"); ?>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import HelloWorld from "@/components/HelloWorld.php";

export default {
  name: "home",
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
};
</script>
```

Changing Home.vue to Home.php dont solve the problem.

Comment: Create two repos, one with vue frontend and other with php backend. Set a hook command using shell (or bat in windows) to run `npm run build` in frontend repo everytime you run some serve, test or deploy command in backend repo.

Answer (score 6):

**You can't.**

VueCLI generates a static project of simply html and javascript. When you run `npm run build` if you look in your `/dist` folder you'll see only `.html` and `.js` files.

If you would like to use data from PHP in a Vue app you would need to add your Vue components to a PHP project and pass data to Vue as props.

Alternatively, a very common approach is to have a separate Vuejs frontend which consumes an API which you could write in PHP.

Comment: In addition here you can find some basic solution: https://makitweb.com/insert-update-delete-records-from-mysql-with-vue-js/